# Software for better dual monitors setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm looking for software, that will keep some programs on the specific screen.

I'm using laptop(with Windows 7) with dock station and two monitors and every time when i eject my monitor from dock station all programs are moving to the laptop screen (that's natural), and after returning back they are staying on the default screen.

Is exist software for mapping specific programs with specific screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use Ultramon at work and home and love it. However, all I wanted is to have the taskbar span my screens and I didn't want anything too bloated. The one feature it's missing though is assigning programs to specific screens. Sometimes prompts from one screen will come up on another screen... which is annoying, but I deal with it.

I did try out [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) when [Scott Hanselman mentioned it on his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2011UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx). At first I really enjoyed it because it did allow you to assign programs to monitors, etc. It gave much more control and the start menu icon was on every screen. After a few days though it got kind of buggy (mainly the task bar became unresponsive). So I ditched it even though it did everything else better. They are coming out with a new version, 4.0, which I do plan to try out once it's out of beta.

Both Ultramon & DisplayFusion have a 30-day trial. After 30 days, you'll either need to upgrade Ultramon or just continue using the free version of DisplayFusion.

I would try them both out (but make sure only one is running at a time) and see what works best for your setup.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional with 8GB of Ram and Xeon W3530 2.8 processor.

Answer (score 2):

Ultramon is pretty good though it's not free...

http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual ultramon? Does it have the feature he wants?

Comment: @SimonSheehan - The link to the website is in the linked article.   I would edit the answer, but I see no reason to, its clear as day.

Comment: @Ramhound we generally prefer people to not just link to Wiki articles, but to explain things here